# Does local convergence in $L^p$ follow from weak convergence of measures and uniform $L^p$ boundedness?

Tags: measure-theory

On page 610 in *Sur les mesures de Wigner* by P.-L. Lions and T. Paul, the authors claim the following:

Let $\mathcal{M}_{w-*}$ be the space of bounded positive measures on $R^d$, equipped with the weak* topology.

Let $f^n$ be a "relatively compact" sequence of functions in $C([-T,T],\mathcal{M}_{w-*})$ converging to $f$ *as measures*. Suppose that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

My question is how to see that.

The convergence "as measures" is IMO to be understood as the weak (or vague) convergence of measures, i.e. $f_n \rightarrow f$ as measures in $\mathcal{M}_{w-*}$ if for all $\varphi \in C_b$,

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} (f_n-f) \varphi dx = 0 $$

As a guess, I would think of Vitali's convergence theorem, where it is required that $f_n \rightarrow f$ *in measure*. This can only mean the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, right? In the sense that for all $\epsilon >0$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lambda(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: |f_n-f| \geq \epsilon\}) = 0$$

Otherwise put,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: |f_n-f| \geq \epsilon\}} dx =0 $$

but I don't know how this relates to the convergence of measures above. I guess the answer is just a simple application of a well-known theorem, but I don't see through the nomenclature.

Comment: In the given reference I do not read exactly the statement you wrote : the convergence is stated for $\nabla V_0 \star \rho^\hbar$ isn't it ?

Comment: The space of bounded  Borel measures on $\mathbb R^d$ is the dual  of $C_0(\mathbb R^d)$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity). So I would say “for all $\phi \in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$ rather than “for all $\phi \in C_b(\mathbb R^d)$

Comment: But what does  *”$f_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$”* mean for a sequence of functions in $C([-T,T],\mathcal{M}_{w-*})$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer I think that they are interpreted as measures in the sense that they define densities, i.e. $\int f_n d x$. If we assume that $f_n \in L^1$, then this is well defined since they are positive.